# $\mathsf{P}^\mathsf{BPP}$ vs $\mathsf{BPP}$ (Are they known to be equal)

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, oracles

> Is it known if $\mathsf{P}^\mathsf{BPP}= \mathsf{BPP}$ ?

It's clear that $\mathsf{BPP} \subseteq \mathsf{P}^\mathsf{BPP}$. Now, since $\mathsf{BPP}$ is closed under complementation, union, and intersection, it seems to provide evidence that $\mathsf{BPP} = \mathsf{P}^\mathsf{BPP}$. However, I can't prove this.

Comment: Is it well defined what it means to have a randomized complexity class (with no complete problems) as an oracle ?

Comment: Suresh: $P^{\mathcal C}$ is well defined for any set of languages $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Can't you trivially simulate each BPP oracle call within your polynomial-time randomized algorithm? You'll just need to improve the error probability of each such simulation to, say, exponentially small so that the total chance of making an error throughout the algorithm stays small enough.

Comment: @Kristoffer would you mind giving the formal definition or confirming if the following is correct? "$P^{BPP}$ is the set of languages decidable in polytime by a deterministic TM with access to a yes/no oracle for some language in $BPP$."

Comment: usul: Your statement is correct.

Comment: (This question is actually mine.) Two comments: 1) Why is it being down voted? I believe the question is well defined and clear. 2) Why is there an "advice-and-nonuniformity" tag? It's known that BPP is in P/poly; but it's also known that BPP is in Sigma_2 P. It's not clear to me why this was auto tagged advice-and-non-uniformity. Thanks.

Comment: It was my mistake. I should have tagged it "relativized" rather than "advice". As for the down vote, I'm not sure. It seems reasonable to me. But with questions like this, it often helps if you can provide some motivation as to why you're asking

Comment: @SureshVenkat: The motivation came from looking at oracle separation results and wondering ... what is the power of a BPP oracle? We know that P^P = P, we also know that P^NP probably != NP, probably != coNP; but for BPP, it's not clear at all to me how powerful it is as an oracle. I'll be sure to add more "motivation" in the future.

Comment: The down-votes are probably because the question looks like a homework which would make it off-topic. Please check the [faq]. As Suresh wrote stating the motivation inside the post would make it clear the question is on-tipic and would help with avoiding down-votes. (Using a real name would also help.)

Comment: PS: I think this is off-topic. The answer is as MCH wrote (i.e. no need to know about lowness).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, since BPP is [low](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_%28complexity%29), but this is not a research level question.

Comment: But it would come under the category of "things that are well known in one subcommunity but not in another"

Comment: I am sure you know these things better than me, but statements like this can be verified with 5 mins googling, imo.

Comment: I agree, once you understand that this notion is linked to the notion of "lowness". but that's probably what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @domotorp: Having just read the proof http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~allender/538/murata3.pdf (linked from your wikipedia article), I do admit: my question was not research level.